# TurboTax - relevance of 1099-R if 401(k) came out of paycheck

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k, form-1099, turbotax

I am doing my taxes using TurboTax (US).

My 401(k) contributions were all on my paychecks, with employer contributions and my own contributions being accounted for in my salary.

With that in mind, do I need to worry about downloading and/or entering a 1099-R form into TurboTax?

Comment: 1099-r is for distribution *from* 401k etc., not for contributions.  (See [Turbotax page on that form](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/1901471-what-is-form-1099-r)).  Did you take a distribution from your 401k (i.e., did you get some money from it) or just make contributions?  Did you have a rollover, conversion, or recharacterization (i.e., move money from one kind of IRA/401k to another kind, particularly involving roth/not roth)?

Comment: That clarified things, thank you. No - I only contributed to the 401(k) (or my employer contributed). Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it :) Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have to file a 1099-R unless you took a distribution from your retirement account, or if you had a rollover, conversion, or recharacterization - particularly between a regular and Roth type account.  If you only contributed to your retirement account(s) and none of those things occurred, then you should not have a 1099-R.